# Post generic class in .net core web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .net core Web API. I'm posting generic QueryFilter class from angular. But, generic part of class return null. When, i change to parameter like this, it is working perfectly :

```
 public async Task<ServiceResult> GetStudentsForGrid([FromQuery]QueryFilter queryFilter,[FromQuery]StudentFilter studentFilter)
 { } //This working perfectly
```

QueryFilter.cs

```
public class QueryFilter<T> where T : class
{
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsSortAscending { get; set; }
    public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
    public byte PageSize { get; set; }
    public T CustomFilter { get; set; }
}
```

StudentFilter.cs

```
public class StudentFilter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Controller.cs **(not working)**

```
 [HttpGet("GetStudentsForGrid")]
 public async Task<ServiceResult> GetStudentsForGrid([FromQuery]QueryFilter<StudentFilter> queryFilter)
 { } //This not working
```

I don't want to send every time two parameter. So, I want to use generic way. How can i fix this null exception?

Comment: What does your request URI end up looking like? I'm not sure how the binding mechanism is supposed to figure out what goes where when you have a nested model and a query string that is by definition "flat", so to speak. Did you try looking into model binders? Just for fun, what happens if you make it a POST and read the model from the JSON request body you send from JS?

Comment: @itminus answer worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a "generic" way , let's say your controller action is :

```
public IActionResult GetStudentsForGrid([FromQuery]QueryFilter<StudentFilter> queryFilter)
{ 
    var x= queryFilter;
    return new JsonResult(x);
}
```

you have to sent the request with a well formatted querystring :

```
GET https://localhost:5001/api/students?sortBy=Hello&pageSize=10&customFilter.Name=1&customFilter.SurName=2 HTTP/1.1
```

Note the way we pass the parameters of `customFilter.Name` and `customFilter.SurName`.

The response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "sortBy": "Hello",
  "isSortAscending": false,
  "pageFirstIndex": 0,
  "pageSize": 10,
  "customFilter": {
    "name": "1",
    "surname": "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @itminus. It worked perfectly. My mistake is; I am posting parameter as "Name" not "customFilter.Name". But, when i used two parameter (non-generic way), c# automatically bind without "customFilter.Name". So, I thinked in generic way will work. But Ilearnt that, generic class is different from normal class. In generic way, i must send as "customFilter.Name" not "Name".

Comment: But in your answer, you convert my original method from "public async Task<ServiceResult> GetStudentsForGrid" to "public IActionResult GetStudentsForGrid". But, it is not necessary. It's also working async Task.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir  That's because I don't have the definition of `ServiceResult`, so I just take the `IActionResult` as an example to test with PostMan to make sure I'm doing the right thing , and also , it will make my example more clean . :)

Comment: You are right.This is more claner. Thanks again @itminus